# Card change size after adding link in grid

Tags: html, css

I made grid gallery and I need to add link to all of cards, but when I add **a** tag, whole card change size. I need to hold size of card and have whole area with link. I can add link in card without size change, but there will be link just text and I need whole card. I tried to change size of link but nothing happend

.
.
.

```css
.feed{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 350px;
    grid-gap: 16px;
    margin: 40px 0px 40px 0px;

}

.card_category{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}
.card_title{
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
#folio{
    padding: 5% 10%;
}
.karta{
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    
}

.karta:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 30px 18px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transform: scale(1.02);
}
.karta:nth-child(1){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(2){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(3){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(4){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(5){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(6){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(7){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(8){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(9){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}

.karta:nth-child(1),:nth-child(6),:nth-child(7){
    grid-column-start: span 6;
}
.karta:nth-child(2),:nth-child(3),:nth-child(4),:nth-child(5),:nth-child(8),:nth-child(9){
    grid-column-start: span 3;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1068px){

    .karta:nth-child(n){
        grid-column-start: span 12;
    }

}
```

```html
    <div class="feed">
       <a href="#"> <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div></a>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think propper way not to put `div` inside `a` tag, but give a necessary `class` to `a` tag. In your case it is `class="karta"`.

Look example in my snippet. I've put the link with class for the first place.

```css
.feed{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 350px;
    grid-gap: 16px;
    margin: 40px 0px 40px 0px;

}

.card_category{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}
.card_title{
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
#folio{
    padding: 5% 10%;
}
.karta{
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    
}

.karta:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 30px 18px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transform: scale(1.02);
}
.karta:nth-child(1){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(2){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(3){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(4){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(5){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(6){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(7){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(8){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}
.karta:nth-child(9){
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
        rgba(10,10,10,0) 100%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579703788936-06e79a4cce27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=584&q=80');
}

.karta:nth-child(1),:nth-child(6),:nth-child(7){
    grid-column-start: span 6;
}
.karta:nth-child(2),:nth-child(3),:nth-child(4),:nth-child(5),:nth-child(8),:nth-child(9){
    grid-column-start: span 3;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1068px){

    .karta:nth-child(n){
        grid-column-start: span 12;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="feed">
         <a href="#" class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </a>
       <a href="#"> <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div></a>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>
        <div class="karta">
            <p class="card_category">Travel</p>
            <p class="card_title">Lost in the city</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
```